# How to get the url of a page via the Notion Public API?

Tags: notion-api

As per the official Notion Public API [documentation](https://developers.notion.com/reference/get-page) about how to retrieve a page, I can get the page properties and a little amount of metadata (ie. "object", "id", "created_time", "last_edited_time").
How can I obtain the page slug or URL given the available metadata? (I am trying to get the page URL for a database item).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query a database using https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/database_id/query and you can find your page id in `results[].id` from the list of responses. Omit dashes from `results[].id`. https://notion.so/page_id will be your page URL.